# How to get two applets to share fields

Tags: java, javascript, applet, japplet

I have two applets.  FirstApplet applet is in the main HTML page.  The main page uses javascript window.open(...) to open a new page where the SecondApplet applet is embedded.

Below is how both applets are defined:

```
public class SecondApplet extends JApplet{
    private static Long value;
    public void init(){
        value = new Long(6);
    }
    public static void testValue(){
        System.out.println(value);
    } 
}

public class FirstApplet extends JApplet{
    public void testValue(){
        SecondApplet.testValue();
    }
}
```

Now my problem is when FirstApplet invokes

```
SecondApplet.testValue()
```

The static field has lost it's value and now it has value of 0.
I also experimented with my own object models where they get instantiated in SecondApplet init() method but when FirstApplet.testValue() is called those objects are now NULL.

Anyone knows why this behavior is occuring?  I'm just puzzled since both Applets live in the same JVM.

BTW, I also tried using getAppletContext.getApplet("secondapplet") but it always returns NULL. Even getAppletContext.getApplets() always returns one element. I verified in HTML pages the  name attribute and it's correct.

If this is security issue, just wanted to add that I get no errors or warnings of any kind.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I'm just puzzled since both Applets live in the same JVM."*  That they are in separate web pages (supposedly in separate frames/tabs as well) combined with 2 pieces of evidence to the contrary, suggests otherwise.

Comment: Can you arrange JS communication between these two pages?  AFAIU that is blocked for security reasons (& if so logically so would an applet).

Comment: I guess I'll go with JavaScript communication.  I didn't know about that Applet to Applet security issue until know.  I wasn't getting any errors/warnings of any kind, so I was confused.

Answer (score -1):

They're in the same JVM, but they're sandboxed. They use a different class loader, and they're prohibited from accessing the other applet's class loader, so they might as well be in a different JVM. This is a security feature. You wouldn't want some malicious applet to access the data in all your open browser windows.

Sharing data between different browser windows is tricky, as it should be. If you really need to do it, you should tell us what your specific requirements are. That is, *why* do you need to share data?

Comment: The last para makes for a +1 comment.  The 1st para. for a -1 answer.  Sand-boxed applets can share non static public attributes in the same JVM.